# NodeJS Http.get() Concatenate Data

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is somehow a basic question but there's really less nodeJS references available. Why does: the line:

```
data += data
```

and

```
data = data
```

From the below code matter? The first one produces twice the actual content of the file provided in the options object, while the latter produces the weird buffer output.

```
http.get(options, (response) => {

    response.on("data", (data) => {
        data += data;
        console.log(data);
    });

    response.on("error", () => {
        console.log("An error has occured. Bummer.");
    });
});
```

Comment: You are adding `data` to `data`. Of course it's going to output twice the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one (`data += data`) appends `data` to `data`, and because of the `+=` an implicit conversion from `Buffer` to `String` is done, because of that you see a string as output for `console.log(data);`.

The second one (`data = data`)  just assigns `data` to `data`, so it does nothing at all. Because of that the type of `data` does not change and is still `Buffer`

If you want to log the content of a buffer as string you would use [buf.toString](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end): `console.log(data.toString())`

Answer (score 1):

In the first line you are concatenating data with itself so it outputs twice the content.

You are wanting to do something like this:

```
var body = "";
request.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk; // string conversion
}).on('end', function() {
    console.log(body);
});
```